# Programmatic configuration of authkey and similar to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, docker

I am using the `kartoza/geoserver-docker` image [link](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver) to serve map layers because I wish to gracefully handle server failures and support scaling if needed.

My docker container has a persistent store for the configuration files but recently we had the configuration become corrupted resulting in an infinite boot, fail, reboot cycle which was unrecoverable until all config files were purged.

Following this I have scripted most of the server config via the REST API so I can restore a server to a working state from a blank install. BUT I cannot find any means to configure the authkey plugin I use and set the auth filter chain or things like server defaults such as which services to enable for all layers. Is there a REST API endpoint undocumented for this or is the only option to just keep a copy of the pre-configured xml files for auth and copy those in when bootstrapping a new container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your pain, I do not believe there is a REST API for the very useful authkey module.  However, what could work for you is the **Key provider using an external web service** option, which we make use of, see:

https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html#key-provider-using-an-external-web-service

Alternatively, restoring your most recent backup of authkey.properties as part of the script is another option.

Comment: Yep, we are using the external web service as the means of minimizing config for the authkey plugin. It isn't unreasonable for REST API functionality to be excluded for this, probably more secure this way. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for the specific config files. If I have any insights I'll post them back here after trying it out.